# Need my listbox to update from a list

Tags: c#, list, listbox, refresh, datasource

I have my listbox1 set to use a datasource of a list called "serverList". When I run

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if (folderPath != "\\realmlist.wtf" && folderPath != "none")
{
    serverList.Add(newServer);
    listBox1.DataSource = serverList;
    File.WriteAllText(folderPath, "Set realmlist " + newServer);
}
}
```

the first string enters and shows up in the listbox just fine but when I try to add another string to the list it wont show up in the listbox but is actually within the list. What can I do to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried rebinding the data after you add the string to the list?  I.e., `listBox1.DataBind();` after you assign the DataSource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if winform app

```
    BindingSource source=new BindingSource();
    source.DataSource=serverList;
    listBox1.DataSource = source;
```

if not you have to use `listBox1.DataBind()`

Comment: This works perfect! Although I don't understand why it does. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

After assigning DataSource, you should bind the data i.e. listBox1.DataBind()

Comment: What is binding data? What does the actually do? I checked msdn but that was not clear at all.

Comment: Actually it establishes the connection between control and data, you care read further [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/06/29/how-asp-net-databinding-deals-with-eval-and-bind-statements.aspx)